# How to prevent User Roles from getting reapplied?

Tags: users

For whatever reason when I remove a role from a user's profile, at url `site/user/user-id/edit` it just comes back a few days later. I tried to check **users_role** table but I do not have that table.

[image].

We do import every employee every night, based off Active Directory, but I do not touch their roles in the import.

I imagine the best way of solving this is finding the table that has every user's roles, then just removing that entry from the particular user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to run this: **`show tables like '%role%';`** MySQL statement. In the results returned you should see a **`users_roles`** table (not **`users_role`**). To that table's columns are stored the `uid` and `rid`, therefore you will be able to find all users that have assigned with a role or more, and possibly an answer to your question.

I would kindly suggest you, since those roles are appeared again and again, to search any by chance or forgotten [user_save](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user.module/function/user_save/7) implementation within your code.

Hope this help!

Comment: Some reason I see **users_roles** as you suggested through cli, but not phpmyadmin - on the left sidebar... I also just found out phpmyadmin does show the **users_roles**, if you click on the database and not view it on the left sidebar. The role saves as not being apart of the user's roles, but after a week or two it reappears. Either way, your answer will solve my issue. My thinking is, I can alter it on the table level. Thank you!

Comment: hmm. When I remove the role from a user's profile, in Drupal's user's profile page, I see the entry from **users_roles** get removed (as we would expect)... but it comes back like a week later... Now I am curious if me removing the entry directly will actually stop this.

Comment: "We do import every employee every night"
I insist to check for any [user_save](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user.module/function/user_save/7) upon the import. 
Hopefully by removing manually from the `db` the roles entries will work. Let us know.

Comment: Good thinking. I checked the module that is used for the cron import, but the module does not use **user_save** anywhere in it. Which I suspected, because this issue does not happen every night, during the import. I did remove a user's role earlier today, on the db level, and that user now has the role again... before the end of the day... Maybe it's when they log in. I'll do some more digging.

Comment: Removed the role from the user, then had them revisit the site, but they did not regain the role. I will check tomorrow and see if it comes back after the midnight cron job.

Comment: Cron import went off fine today, and the user does not have the role... So, back to the drawing board. I think if I monitor the user all day, log the time they get the role (if it happens), and then look at the cron jobs around that time to see if something is being triggered, it might lead me to the solution.